# How to speed up my procedure and program?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a stored procedure, when I run the query in SQL Server, I got the result in 2 seconds, but when I call the procedure from the program, it takes 40 seconds.

How can I speed up my program when calling the procedure?

The stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[SearchOrdersPrice]
    @Criteria VARCHAR(50)
AS
    SELECT 
        [Lab_Orders].ORDER_ID AS 'Order Number',
        [ORDER_DATE] AS 'Order Date',
        Patients.Patient_Name AS 'Patient Name',
        Patients.Age AS 'Patient Age',
        LabTests.TestName AS 'Test Name',
        Customers.CustName AS 'Customer Name',
        Invoice_order_no AS 'Request Form Number',
        [ORDER_DESCRIPTION] AS 'Diagnosis',
        Lab_Orders.USER_ID AS 'Requested By User',
        Order_Details.TOTAL_AMOUNT AS 'Total Amount'
    FROM 
        Lab_Orders
    INNER JOIN
        Order_Details ON Order_Details.ORDER_ID = Lab_Orders.ORDER_ID 
    INNER JOIN
        Customers ON Customers.CustId = Lab_Orders.CUSTID
    INNER JOIN
        patients ON Patients.Patient_No = Lab_Orders.patient_no
    INNER JOIN
        LabTests ON LabTests.TestId =  Order_Details.TESTID
    WHERE 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, [Lab_Orders].ORDER_ID) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, [ORDER_DATE]) + CustName + ORDER_DESCRIPTION + TestName + USER_ID + PATIENT_NAME + CONVERT(VARCHAR, AGE) + Invoice_order_no + TOTAL_AMOUNT LIKE '%'+ @Criteria +'%'
        AND Lab_Orders.order_status = 1
    ORDER BY
        [Lab_Orders].ORDER_ID DESC
```

My C# (Windows Forms code): I have a button when I press it, I call another window and call the procedure and get data.

The button handler code :

```
private void btnSelectOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkvalue = checkCASH.Checked;
    VIEW_ORDER_DETAILS orders = new VIEW_ORDER_DETAILS();
    orders.ShowDialog();

    if (checkCASH.Checked == true)
    {
        try
        {
            cashPatient = 1;
            this.txtOrder.Text = orders.OrdersDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            txtOrder.Focus();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select Order Number");
        }
    }

    if (checkCASH.Checked == false)
    {
        try
        {
            cashPatient = 2;
            this.txtOrder.Text = orders.OrdersDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            txtOrder.Focus();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select Order Number");
        }
    }
}
```

The other window page load code:

```
public VIEW_ORDER_DETAILS()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Size = new Size(1700, 600);

    if (LAB_SAMPLES.checkvalue == true)
    {
        OrdersDataGridView.DataSource = order.SearchOrdersPricecash("");
    }
    else
    {
        OrdersDataGridView.DataSource = order.SearchOrdersPrice("");
    }
}
```

This is the calling method:

```
public DataTable SearchOrdersPrice(string order_id)
{
    DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Criteria", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    param[0].Value = order_id;

    dt = DAL.SelectData("SearchOrdersPrice", param);
    DAL.close();

    return dt;
}
```

This is the DAL code:

```
class DataAccessLayer
{
    SqlConnection sqlconnection;

    // this initialize the connection to the database
    public DataAccessLayer()
    {
        sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(@"");
    }

    // method to open the connection 
    public void open()
    {
        if (sqlconnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            sqlconnection.Open();
        } 
    }

    // method to close the connection 
    public void close()
    {
        if (sqlconnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            sqlconnection.Close();
        }
    }

    // method to read data from database 
    public DataTable SelectData(string stored_procedure, SqlParameter[] param)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcmd.CommandText = stored_procedure;
        sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconnection;

        if (param != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
            {
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
            }
        }

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        return dt;
    }

    // Method to insert update and delete date from database 
    public void ExecuteCommand (string stored_procedure , SqlParameter[] param)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcmd.CommandText = stored_procedure;
        sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconnection;

        if (param != null)
        {
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        }

        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I tried to solve my issue by using parameter sniffing but its not solving the issue :

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[SearchOrdersPrice]
@Criteria varchar(50)
as
begin 
declare @localCriteria varchar(50) 
set @localCriteria = @Criteria

SELECT [Lab_Orders].ORDER_ID as 'Order Number'
      ,[ORDER_DATE] as 'Order Date'
      ,Patients.Patient_Name as 'Patient Name'
      ,Patients.Age as 'Patient Age'
      ,LabTests.TestName as 'Test Name'
      ,Customers.CustName as 'Customer Name'
      ,Invoice_order_no as 'Request Form Number'
      ,[ORDER_DESCRIPTION] as 'Diagnosis'
      ,Lab_Orders.USER_ID as 'Requested By User'
      ,Order_Details.TOTAL_AMOUNT as 'Total Amount'


  FROM Lab_Orders
  inner join Order_Details on Order_Details.ORDER_ID= Lab_Orders.ORDER_ID 
  inner join Customers on Customers.CustId = Lab_Orders.CUSTID
  inner join patients on Patients.Patient_No = Lab_Orders.patient_no
  inner join LabTests on LabTests.TestId =  Order_Details.TESTID

where CONVERT(varchar,[Lab_Orders].ORDER_ID) + CONVERT(varchar,[ORDER_DATE]) + CustName+ORDER_DESCRIPTION+TestName+
       + USER_ID + PATIENT_NAME + CONVERT (varchar,AGE)+Invoice_order_no+TOTAL_AMOUNT like '%'+ @localCriteria +'%'
and Lab_Orders.order_status=1
order by [Lab_Orders].ORDER_ID desc
end
```

Then I removed the parameter from the stored procedure and still same time taking 40 seconds when calling the procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[SearchOrdersPrice]
as

SELECT [Lab_Orders].ORDER_ID as 'Order Number'
      ,[ORDER_DATE] as 'Order Date'
      ,Patients.Patient_Name as 'Patient Name'
      ,Patients.Age as 'Patient Age'
      ,LabTests.TestName as 'Test Name'
      ,Customers.CustName as 'Customer Name'
      ,Invoice_order_no as 'Request Form Number'
      ,[ORDER_DESCRIPTION] as 'Diagnosis'
      ,Lab_Orders.USER_ID as 'Requested By User'
      ,Order_Details.TOTAL_AMOUNT as 'Total Amount'


  FROM Lab_Orders
  inner join Order_Details on Order_Details.ORDER_ID= Lab_Orders.ORDER_ID 
  inner join Customers on Customers.CustId = Lab_Orders.CUSTID
  inner join patients on Patients.Patient_No = Lab_Orders.patient_no
  inner join LabTests on LabTests.TestId =  Order_Details.TESTID

where Lab_Orders.order_status=1
order by [Lab_Orders].ORDER_ID desc
```

Comment: Consider using a micro-ORM like Dapper instead of this old, outdated ADO code.

Comment: You haven't supplied the code for your DAL, so we have no idea what's going on in there.

Comment: @Robert Harvey , How to use micro-ORM ? I added the complete DAL code

Comment: See https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

Comment: Your problem is going to be the `DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)` call. As already mentioned, this ancient code should be thrown out and something simpler and faster, like Dapper, put in its place.

Comment: An ORM is not going to automatically make this faster. Are you using identical parameters when you notice the performance difference? For these symptoms the issue is often parameter sniffing.

Comment: See msdn article on using dbContext to run stored procedure and put results into a datatable : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Stored-Procedure-with-6c194514

Comment: Some tips: `DataAccessLayer` holds a `SqlConnection` in a field. SqlConnection is IDisposable, so as it stands, DataAccessLayer [needs to be IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1001-types-that-own-disposable-fields-should-be-disposable); but you may find it solves your problem to avoid doing this by having the connection as a `using` block around each command. SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter are both IDisposable as well, so each of those should be in a `using` block.

Comment: @IanKemp can you please add the suggested answer how to update the code and using Dapper.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid No i am using same parameters but its faster before now when the data increased and became bigger its became slow

Comment: @Richardissimo Can you please add suggested answer.

Comment: Are you saying that my comment solved your problem, and that you want me to add it as an answer so that you can accept it? Or are you just asking me to provide an answer which I have not yet offered?

Comment: Just linking this to another similar question. Note: it doesn't have an accepted answer, but one of the answers corresponds with the only answer offered so far (i.e. it didn't fix it for that person either)... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702583/sql-stored-procedure-execution-time-difference Here's another offering the same solution which was accepted... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958604/stored-procedure-taking-time-in-execution Here's one with the same scenario and different answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351290/stored-procedure-is-taking-time-in-execution

Comment: Here's another question with the same scenario... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898911/stored-procedure-time-out-but-fine-when-run-from-ssms Here's the same scenario for someone using EntityFramework to show what Nick said, that ORMs are not a magic cure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700687/entity-framework-extremely-long-execution-time-for-stored-procedure

Comment: @Richardissimo ok thank you, yes i need the answer i will try the links you provide and tell you if it work or not.

Comment: It's not my responsibility to provide you with the answer. Everyone here is volunteering their own time, so it is not reasonable to demand that I solve your problem. If you read [ask] it's **your** responsibility to do the research that I did above (and I stopped after finding those - there are probably others), and you should explain in the question why those other questions are different than yours, or why those answers don't work for you. It's worth reading https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: @Richardissimo Yes you are right sorry for that just i need help, i used parameter sniffing from the link but its not solving my issue and still taking 40 seconds, then i removed the parameter from the stored procedure and where condition but its still taking long time when calling the procedure.

Comment: So you still have the situation where it's fast in SSMS and slow in the app? And you tried `WITH RECOMPILE` without any difference? and you are convinced you are using identical parameters? When you _remove_ the parameter, surely it takes longer in the application as well, because it's not filtering data? What I would do  now is capture the two different queries with SQL Profiler and compare them, particularly parameter values and `SET` options

Comment: Just as an experiment can you run the proc in SSMS but put `SET ARITHABORT OFF` at the start and see  if you can reproduce the 40 minute issue? If it does reproduce it, it's definitely parameter sniffing

Comment: Did you resolve this yet?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean no not yet , I deleted some old data from database table and its faster now but this is not the solution i will try more solutions .

Comment: How many records does that query return when it is slow?

Comment: its not big around 5000 records only

Comment: And is the 40s spent almost entirely the database call? Have you stepped over the code to see where the 40s is allocated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improving performance you can try your stored procedure with `With Recompile` like in this code shown here; hope this work for you.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchOrdersPrice]
    @Criteria VARCHAR(50)
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
    SELECT 
        [Lab_Orders].ORDER_ID AS 'Order Number',
        [ORDER_DATE] AS 'Order Date',
        Patients.Patient_Name AS 'Patient Name',
        Patients.Age AS 'Patient Age',
        LabTests.TestName AS 'Test Name',
        Customers.CustName AS 'Customer Name',
        Invoice_order_no AS 'Request Form Number',
        [ORDER_DESCRIPTION] AS 'Diagnosis',
        Lab_Orders.USER_ID AS 'Requested By User',
        Order_Details.TOTAL_AMOUNT AS 'Total Amount'
    FROM 
        Lab_Orders
    INNER JOIN
        Order_Details ON Order_Details.ORDER_ID = Lab_Orders.ORDER_ID 
    INNER JOIN
        Customers ON Customers.CustId = Lab_Orders.CUSTID
    INNER JOIN
        patients ON Patients.Patient_No = Lab_Orders.patient_no
    INNER JOIN
        LabTests ON LabTests.TestId =  Order_Details.TESTID
    WHERE 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, [Lab_Orders].ORDER_ID) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, [ORDER_DATE]) + CustName + ORDER_DESCRIPTION + TestName + USER_ID + PATIENT_NAME + CONVERT(VARCHAR, AGE) + Invoice_order_no + TOTAL_AMOUNT LIKE '%'+ @Criteria +'%'
        AND Lab_Orders.order_status = 1
    ORDER BY
        [Lab_Orders].ORDER_ID DESC
```